# ParseException Error using Regex in pyspark 2.4

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am trying to get only those rows where colADD contain non alphanumeric character.

Code :

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession \
     .builder \
     .appName("Test") \
     .getOrCreate()

data = spark.read.csv("Customers");



data.registerTempTable("data");
spark.sql("SELECT colADD from data WHERE colADD REGEXP '^[A-Za-z0-9]+$'; ");
```

Error:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException: u"\nextraneous input ';' 
expecting <EOF>(line 1, pos 56)\n\n== SQL ==\nSELECT CNME from data WHERE CNME REGEXP '^[A-Za-z0-9]+$';
```

Please help, am i missing somethhing.

Comment: which spark version are you using?

Comment: @MaheshGupta: 2.4.4

Comment: try this: spark.sql("SELECT col2 from test WHERE col2 REGEXP '^[A-Za-z0-9]+$' ").show(truncate = False)
 replace column name with your column name. Let me know if you face the same error again

Comment: should I add this as Answer and you could accept it

Comment: @MaheshGupta: sorry, this is not throwing error but not catching the record, one of the record contain as '-', but it is not coming in output.kindly suggest

Comment: you need to check your regexp for catching "-"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199890/discussion-between-sophie-dinka-and-mahesh-gupta).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> spark  used this

```
spark.sql("SELECT col2 from test WHERE col2 REGEXP '^[A-Za-z0-9]*\\-' ").show
```

Answer (score 0):

Have note used pyspark - but how about just removing the `;` - seems not to be needed.